# CSS selector for table with no rows in the tbody

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can select a table with no rows in the tbody using the following jQuery selector:

```
$("table:not(:has(>tbody>tr))")
```

I would like to do this in a pure CSS way, but `:has` is a jQuery selector, so I can not use that in my style sheet.

Any tips?

Comment: If a table has no rows in the tbody...it's not much of table is it? Why would you display a table that has no data?

Comment: @Paulie_D: In this case the table structure (header/footer) is loaded with the page and the rows are added after page load via AJAX.

Comment: @Martin: The question you refer to is not entirely similar as I'm trying to find a CSS equivalent for `:has`.

Comment: Your jQuery selector isn't quite right either - `tbody:not(tr)` means `tbody` that is not `tr`, which would select every `table` that has a `tbody`... the jQuery selector should be `$("table:not(:has(>tbody>tr))")`.

Comment: @BoltClock: You are so right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible through css. You will have to keep using jQuery/js for this.

A list of all CSS Selectors is here:

[CSS Selector List](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)